# Ubuntu 20.04 - cant get sounds anymore on dell T7610

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa

After running an upgrade I dont have sound anymore

hereafter a few parameters of my system

uname -a
Linux ap3 5.8.0-51-generic #57~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 12:34:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci -v | grep Audio

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell C600/X79 series chipset High Definition Audio Controller
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller

aplay --list-devices

aplay: device_list:276: no soundcards found...

I followed a few posts and tried to put

## Added to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

and also
#Added to
blacklist snd_soc_skl /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

All this with no success

When I lauch volume control I have a dummy output instead of the usual phyical output - Speaker or headphones

If anyone can assist with this
Regards,

[Volume control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib9LN.png)

Comment: Same exact symptoms here, but on a HP elitebook G6.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the exact same issue with HP Elitebook G6. I was seeing this in dmesg:

```
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    2.909867] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    2.909871] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    2.909880] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    2.910035] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.185589] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.192846] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.213728] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.213732] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.213739] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 4
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.518745] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: cl_dsp_init: timeout HDA_DSP_SRAM_REG_ROM_STATUS read
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.518812] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: status = 0x00000000 panic = 0x00000000
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.877800] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: cl_dsp_init: timeout HDA_DSP_SRAM_REG_ROM_STATUS read
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    3.877805] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: status = 0x00000000 panic = 0x00000000
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.180322] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: cl_dsp_init: timeout HDA_DSP_SRAM_REG_ROM_STATUS read
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.180331] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: status = 0x00000000 panic = 0x00000000
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.180339] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: dsp init failed after 3 attempts with err: -110
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.180353] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: status = 0xffffffff panic = 0xffffffff
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.180357] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to reset DSP
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.180358] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to boot DSP firmware -110
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.230811] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: hda_dsp_core_reset_enter: timeout on HDA_DSP_REG_ADSPCS read
Jun 17 15:41:00 LE1046 kernel: [    4.230813] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: dsp core reset failed: core_mask f
```

This seemed to do the trick for me:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-fix.conf <<<'options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0'
```

and

```
sudo reboot
```

I was able to see my soundcard in the settings and no longer the dummy output.

[image]